# Disable button during weekend and off businees hour

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datetime, time

example 1: this code will disable a button during weekend

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<style>
.disabled {
  background: grey;
}
</style>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="myButton">Press me only on weekday</button>

<script>
$(function() {
  var now = new Date(),
      days = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'],
      day = days[now.getDay()],

      $button = $('#myButton');

  if (day === days[0] || day === days[6]) {
      $button.addClass('disabled');
  }

  $button.click(function() {
      if ($(this).hasClass('disabled')) {
          alert('We are not accepting entries during weekends.')
          return;
      }
  });
})
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

example 2: this code will disable during off hours and only available during 5:00PM(17:00) - 12:00AM (24:00) in weekdays. Clock location base on +8 UTC

```
<input class="submit" type="submit" id="checktime" value="Check"/>

<script type="text/javascript" defer="defer">
<!-- 
var enableDisable = function(){
    var UTC_hours = new Date().getUTCHours() +8;
    if (UTC_hours > 17 && UTC_hours < 24){
        document.getElementById('checktime').disabled = false;
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('checktime').disabled = true;
    }
};
setInterval(enableDisable, 1000*60);
enableDisable();
// -->
</script>
```

my problem is, I need to combine both of this code so that I can achieve something like this..

> User only allow to clicking the button during 5:00PM(17:00) - 12:00AM
>   (24:00) in weekday and on the weekend the button will be disabled.
>   Button needed to show a alert message if user click it during off
>   day/hour

how to combine this two script properly to make like this? thanks

Answer (score 2):

This will add the disabled attribute when it's between 12:00 am and 5:00 pm (on any day) or when the current day is Saturday or Sunday. Then show an alert if the button is clicked and disabled.

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        var now = new Date(),
        days = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'],
  day = days[now.getDay()],
        UTC_hours = new Date().getUTCHours() +8;
        $button = $('#myButton');

        if (day === days[0] || day === days[6] || (UTC_hours >= 0 && UTC_hours < 17)) {
            $button.prop( "disabled", true );
        } else {
            $button.prop( "disabled", false );
        }

        $button.click(function() {
            if ($(this).is(':disabled')) {
                alert('We are not accepting entries during weekends.')
                return;
            }
        });
   })
</script>
```

Comment: On a side note, this probably isn't the best way to guarantee they can't submit an entry during these times. With browser developer tools, you could remove the disabled attribute fairly easily. If you don't have similar checks on the back end to prevent submissions, you probably would be better off either adding those or removing the button entirely during those times using JS and replacing it with the message.

Comment: I like your solution, but also agree with your side note. This is something that I would do on the server side.

Comment: interesting, but how to make it showing a message during weekday if user clicking the button off hour and not from 5-12?

Comment: Sorry, misread the requirements. Now it should disable the button if the time is between 12:00 am and 5:00 pm and allow clicks from 5:00 pm to 12:00 am.

Comment: when I click the button.. it showing the alert message while button is disabled.. when I click the button.. the button still react as submit button and proceed to submit... do you know how to disable it properly?

Comment: I changed my answer to use jQuery to set the disabled attribute instead of your disabled class. That should prevent the button from being clickable when the disabled attribute is set.